# I have drawn multiple lines, how do I get the beginning and ending coordinates?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have large scrollable image and I am drawing multiple lines using canvas. I want to get the starting and ending coordinates (x,y) of that specific line, which is clicked by the user. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, let's see how do you draw the lines on the canvas and then we'll comment - ok? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store coordinates to draw and also detect collision with the lines.

Comment: No, but would be helpfull if u post the code you already have

Comment: sorry to say I am unable to understand how collision  will helpful for me?

Comment: at the moment you draw lines into a canvas, that information is lost into the drawing, but you must have a virtual representation of the line that was drawn in memory so you can keep track of the drawn and also calculate touchs in lines based in events.

Comment: that is the problem I am unable to find starting coordinates and ending coordinates on touch event of a specific line, How can I do this?

Comment: Store the coordinates in your view class bro, or do image analysis and find the points (do not even ask about that)